# Integrating $\frac{df}{f}$

Tags: calculus

I know the general solution to $\dfrac{df}{dt}=f$ is $f(t)=e^tC$. But how does one compute it from integrating both sides of $\dfrac{df}{f}=dt$? The left part does not seem to make any sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int\frac{df}{f}=\log\left(|f|\right)=\int dt=t+C_1$$
so
$$f=Ce^t$$
where $C=\pm e^{C_1}$

Answer (score 1):

"Integrating" on  both sides gives you $$\int \frac 1 f df = \int 1 dt \\ \ln (f) = t + C \\ f = e^{t+C} = e^Ce^t$$ Note that this is an abuse of notation, you can't multiply by dt.

Comment: Of course you can't, but it works so fine ;)

Comment: (did you mean to say $\int \frac{df}{f}$ rather than $\int \frac{df}{f} df$?)

Comment: That is what I meant to say